# Pronunciation of 'preface'. Why so?

Tags: pronunciation

As one pronounces 'pre' and 'face' as is done for these as individual words, how come when they form the word 'preface' the pronunciation is so different?

Comment: Why should it be the same?

Comment: Why should it be different? :-) I'm already guessing, but I could be wrong, that the pronunciation of 'preface' might have followed,  since long ago, the French word, while the separate words pre and face have had a different origin/history or evolution?

Comment: _Pre-_ isn't an English word, by the way, it's a prefix.

Comment: What about *surface* -- you didn't ask!

Comment: @Kris: Right,  - and this one might not fit as did preface in a cultural/religious context...

Comment: You need to preface all comments with the ID of who you address them to: like, @Bra...  (You will get the prompt with full ID, click to accept it.)

Comment: @Kris: I understand now.

Comment: @Kris _Surface_ does have the same etymology as _face_; I presume that vowel reduction is the main reason for the different pronunciation, as _face_ is unstressed in both _surface_ and _preface._

Comment: @BraddSzonye You are of course right to point out that 'pre' is a prefix, not a word. My mistake for being too relaxed here. However, let me emphasize that it is precisely for it being a prefix that I was so perplexed the pronunciation had to change... As in most cases, 'pre' wouldn't alter the pronunciation, would it?

Comment: It depends on whether the prefix changes the stress of the word and somewhat on the original vowel. For example, _prepare_ has a stressed _a,_ but _preparation_ shifts the stress to the first syllable, reducing the _a_ to an r-colored schwa.

Answer (score 6):

[*Preface*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=preface&allowed_in_frame=0) is derived from Old French *preface* “opening part of sung devotions,” ultimately from Medieval Latin *prefatia.* It is **not** derived from the English word *face* – that's from Old French *face* and Latin *facies* “appearance, form, figure.”

That said, even if they were etymologically related, English stems sometimes change pronunciation when you change the word stress (as often happens when adding affixes or changing the part of speech). For example, *office* has very different vowels from *official.*

---

Edit: For a more thorough explanation of this phenomenon, you can read about [stress and vowel reduction in English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_and_vowel_reduction_in_English). In words like *preface* and *surface,* the stress is on the first syllable, which reduces the vowel of *face* to a [schwa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa).

Comment: So? Whence the *əs /is*?

Comment: @Kris I moved my comment about vowel reduction and schwa into the answer, as that explains why _face_ changes pronunciation when it falls in an unstressed syllable.